# jquery plugin 'blockUI' doesn't gray out screen in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, blockui, jquery-blockui

I'm attempting to use blockUI to block the interface of my web app while performing an ajax operation, but the screen was refusing to gray out for me in firefox (although the message box does show up). I finally figured out that everything was working except the calls to jquery's fadeIn or show.

blockUI starts with elements that have explicitly declared styles of "display: none;" and calls jquery's "fadeIn()" or "show()" functions do display them. Is there anything I'm missing in either jquery or blockUI that would explain this behavior?

Edit: I just discovered that the code works find in Windows Firefox; the issue I am having is on Ubuntu. I do not know whether it affects OS X or not.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a small test case on JSFiddle?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/kvKcC/6/

Comment: I've confirmed the above doesn't work in firefox 8 on ubuntu 11.10, whereas chrome has no trouble with it.

Comment: I just discovered the issue appears to be limited to Ubuntu (haven't tried OS X). I've noted it above.

Comment: I played with it for a minute, and it's odd. In FF in Linux Mint, the overlay comes up fine (it actually does block the stuff behind it), but it's missing the background-color and opacity styles. So it looks like in FF, it's ignoring the `blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS` piece. In Chrome, those styles are set directly on the HTML overlay element, so it looks right. But I know nothing about blockUI, so that's as far as I can go.

Comment: That's exactly the behavior that I experienced on Ubuntu. I mentioned that blockUI uses jQuery's "fadeIn()" and "show()" functions to show the divs, but that doesn't explain the problem since it performs those functions on the confirmation dialogue as well - and that works. I tracked the operation down to lines 339-355 of jquery.blockUI.js [if (opts.fadeIn)]

Comment: Just updated to Firefox 9.0.1; the new version still exhibits the same problem

Comment: @JoBu1324 I think I found the solution from the plugin's website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution according to the [plugin's FAQ](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#faq)

Why don't I see overlays in FF on Linux?

Several people informed me that full page opacity rendering in FF/Linux is crazy slow, so by default it's disabled for that platform. You can enable it by overriding the `applyPlatformOpacityRules` property like this:

```
// enable transparent overlay on FF/Linux 
$.blockUI.defaults.applyPlatformOpacityRules = false;
```